# Why is the urllib library not printing collected data?

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib

```
import urllib
import re

symbolslist = ["AAPL", "SPY", "GOOG","NFLX"]

for symbol in symbolslist:
    url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=%s&   ql=1"%(symbol)
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    regex =  <span id="yfs_184_%s">(.+?)</span> %(symbol.lower())
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    price = re.findall(pattern, htmltext)
    print price
```

Just trying to extract stock data from yahoo finance. The syntax is correct, it just prints blank square brackets instead of the stock data in it. If someone knows what the problem is I'd really appreciate some help.

Comment: Beware, the span id will probably change.

Answer (score 1):

The span id has `l84`, not `184`, fix that and it works. Also, you may want to get rid of the space in the URL, and put single quotes around the regex pattern

```
regex = '<span id="yfs_l84_%s">(.+?)</span>' % symbol.lower()
```

Edit: You can also just get price (and more) from Yahoo in CSV, and transfer far less data, for example for AAPL:

```
http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=aapl&f=snl1d1t1c1w
```

`f` is format, and there is a [blog post](http://www.jarloo.com/yahoo_finance/) which lists some values, but I can't seem to find a reference from Yahoo.